# Optional keys in string formats using '%' operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

Is is possible to have optional keys in [string formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) using '%' operator?
I’m using the **logging** API with Python 2.7, so I can't use [Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

My problem is as follow:

```
>>> import logging

>>> FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s %(user)s'
>>> logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)

>>> logging.warning("It works for:", extra={'user': 'me'})
2016-08-29 11:24:31,262 It works for: me

>>> logging.warning("It does't work!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file <input>, line 1
```

I want to have an empty string for *user* if missing. How can I do that?

I tried with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but it fails:

```
>>> import collections
>>> extra = collections.defaultdict(unicode)
>>> logging.warning("It does't work!", extra=extra)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file <input>, line 1
```

By contrast, with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/), we can do:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.Template('name: {{ name }}, email: {{ email }}').render(name="me")
u'name: me, email: '
```

=> no exception here, just an empty string (for "email").

Comment: I don't know about optionals template variable at this time. However, you can try something like this sort: `logging.warning("It works for:", extra={'user': user if 'user' in vars() else ''})`

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule: this is not what I want. When I log a message, I want to have the choice to use *extra* attributes or not. But I'd like to report extra attributes if they exist using the log format. See also the behavior of Jinja2 in my edit.

Comment: iterate over the dictionary to construct ur string

Comment: @Mox: Are you suggesting me to reimplement the '%' operator?

Comment: yes that is probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: alternatively use if else to check if user exist. generate a different format string based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) The `defaultdict` approach works fine, but only if used directly.

```
>>> import collections
>>> dd=collections.defaultdict(str)
>>> dd['k'] = 22
>>> '%(k)s %(nn)s' % dd
'22 '
```

---

B) The `extra` argument to a log function is used as described in the docs, i.e. not directly as shown above. That's why using a `defaultdict` instead of a regular `dict` does not make a difference.

> The third keyword argument is extra which can be used to pass a
>   dictionary which is used to populate the **dict** of the LogRecord
>   created for the logging event with user-defined attributes.

---

C) You can use a logging filter to take care of the missing extra data:

```
import logging

class UserFilter:
    def filter(self, record):
        try:
            record.user
        except AttributeError:
            record.user = '<N/A>'
        return True

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s %(user)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logging.getLogger().addFilter(UserFilter())

logging.warning("It works for:", extra={'user': 'me'})

logging.warning("It doesn't work!")
# DATE TIME It doesn't work! <N/A>
```

Any class with a `filter` method is fine. It can modify the record in-place and it must return `True` for accepting the record or `False` for filtering it out.