# How string formats '%' operator is implemented?

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

How does string formats '%' operator is implemented in CPython 2.7?

Can't find any reference in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

Well, I fact I found the topic: [String conversion and formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/conversion.html), for `PyOS_snprintf`and `PyOS_vsnprintf`. But not sure it match my question.

See also my question [Optional keys in string formats using '%' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203016/optional-keys-in-string-formats-using-operator)

Comment: documentation is not about implementation, you need to look in source code.

Comment: for python3 - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h

Comment: @YOU that's the new-style formatting

Comment: Try this `print help("%")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is in the [`PyString_Format`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L4229) that is called by the [`string_mod` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L3743) in `Objects/stringobject.c`. The latter in turn is a slot method stored in [`PyString_Type->tp_as_number->nb_remainder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#L3761).

The functions `PyOS_*snprintf` are not really related to the implementation of `str.__mod__`.

Comment: Thanks, and the documentation says: "fmt%(v1,v2,...) is roughly equivalent to sprintf(fmt, v1, v2, ...)"

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE it should probably say `fmt % (v1,v2,...)` is almost but not quite entirely unlike `sprintf(fmt, v1, v2, ...)`.